# In .net core 2.1 console application How can I add controllers in a class library project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I my old windows service application i have a class library project where i have hosted some Api controller. in that application i have following code there

```
public class ApiControllerManger
{
    private static readonly WebApiConfig OWebApiConfig = new WebApiConfig();
    private static void RegisterApi()
    {
        OWebApiConfig.Register(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiListener"]);
    }
}
public class WebApiConfig
{

    private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
    public void Register(string url)
    {
        try
        {

            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(url);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            _server.OpenAsync().Wait();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have referenced the libraries 
System.Net.Http.dll
System.Net.Http.Formatting
System.Web.Http
System.Web.Http.SelfHost

But I can't able to do same in .net core application where main application is a console application, this console application is referencing a  class libary project where i need to add controllers.
Have any body done implementation like this?

Comment: Why would you ever want controllers to live in a Console application project?

Comment: ASP.NET Core applications are console applications to begin with.If you don't *configure* them to use IIS or NGINX as a reverse proxy they start up their own server. Perhaps the real question is *how do I put my controllers in a separate assembly ? Just put them there as you would any class, ensuring you don't mix up namespaces. The conventions are based on namespaces and class names, not source file location

Comment: I suspect you should also check [Create reusable UI using the Razor Class Library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio). You can package all UI components (pages, controllers, views, page models etc) in a separate reusable class library. Idenity's UI for example is packaged in a single assembly

Comment: @maccettura - to be pedantic, controllers live in a console app in .net core, that's precisely how self-hosting works.

Comment: OP - I suspect your controllers are doing too much. They should serve as a thin facade to services in some business/logic 'layer' somewhere. It's that layer that would be most suited to distribution rather than controllers specific to a web context.

Comment: My application basically an old .net 4.5.2 windows service converted to .net core. in that application there are certain web api exposed doing some callbacks and other processing. i can do it easily via http listener and httpcontext thing but wanted to follow standard web api controllers.

Comment: Main problem is which nuget package to reference i my class library project